# How to use both BOOST_PARAM_TEST_CASE and BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE and avoid referencing all tests from main()?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

I am learning to use Boost unit tests and I am seeing lot of conflicting methods to write them. My ideal unit test system does not require referencing individual tests from some root file, and to that end `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE` seems to exist. So I started like this:

#### `tests_main.cpp`

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "Root file for all tests"
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
```

#### `test_simple_thing.cpp`

```
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/parameterized_test.hpp>

using namespace boost::unit_test;

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_fixed_str)

namespace unit
{
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_add)
{
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(1+1, 2);
}
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

But I also need parametric tests, and there will be lot of them most likely. I have `constexpr std::array`s defined and I will want to test for each entry where it makes sense.

I found this way:

```
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/test/parameterized_test.hpp>

#include <array>

constexpr std::array numbers{
 2, 4, 6, 8
};

void my_param_test(const int& number)
{
  BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(number%2, 0);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()

test_suite* init_unit_test_suite( int /*argc*/, char* /*argv*/[] )
{

  framework::master_test_suite().add(BOOST_PARAM_TEST_CASE(&my_param_test, std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers)));
  return 0;
}
```

Note the difference between `test/included/unit_test.hpp` and `test/unit_test.hpp`, the former may only be included in one cpp file.

And so, the above code will cause duplicate linker errors. Even if you remove `/included/`, `init_unit_test_suite` is already duplicated by `tests_main.cpp`. If you remove it, the parametric tests are not tests anymore, just random functions.

So how can I combine these two?

I can't figure how to make this range based test using the first method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [data test cases](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/tests_organization/test_cases/test_case_generation/datasets_auto_registration.html):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28f67cdb8480417b)**

```
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE "Root file for all tests"
#include <array>
#include <boost/test/data/test_case.hpp>
#include <boost/test/included/unit_test.hpp>

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(test_fixed_str)

namespace unit {
    BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(test_add) {//
        BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(1 + 1, 2);
    }
} // namespace unit

constexpr std::array numbers{2, 4, 6, 8};

BOOST_DATA_TEST_CASE(my_param_test, numbers, number) { //
    BOOST_TEST((number <= 4 && number >= 0));
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()
```

Which already does the expected:

[image]

Comment: I found these, but I did not really like the macro approach for parametrized tests. I have in the end made my own system to register functions as tests, but this is probably the correct approach